# Why do air-to-air missiles have tail fins?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

That sounds like a stupid question but hear me out.

For something like a rocket where the goal is to fly in a straight line the use of the tail fins is obvious. But air-to-air missiles are designed to be maneuverable. Aim9 sidewinder pictured:

[image: aim9 sidewinder]

Wouldn't having large tail fins spoil this maneuverability? If anything, I would expect the fins to be somewhere near the CG, like an airplanes wings. A plane with large wings at the back would fly like a dart, even with canards near the nose.

On some missiles like the Javelin, the fins are placed this way.
[image: javelin missile after launch]

And on some anti aircraft missiles like the stinger there are barely any fins at all. (there are canards which haven't deployed yet in the picture).

[image: stinger missile in flight]

Obviously it's convenient to not have large fins, but why can this work for the stinger and not for larger missiles like the sidewinder?

My *guess* is that the high speed of missiles like the sidewinder gives the tube enough body lift to maneuver the missile, and some additional stability is needed. Whereas the much slower javelin does not have enough "grip" on the air just from the missile body.

Is that true? Or are there other factors at play?

Comment: A dart doesn't have control surfaces.

Comment: The aviation SE might have betters answers.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that a dart has high stability and poor maneuverability, so it seems like a poor layout for a missile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't (or rather, it is tricky) to produce lift to keep aloft AND independently apply moments for maneuvering with just one pair of airfoils. That would be a flying wing which is not exactly known for maneuverability or ease of design.

If there were no gravity then you would only need one set of fins to push about the COG to produce a moment for maneuvering, but on Earth we have gravity to deal with.

For an airplane or cruise missile when you want efficiency you have a big set of lift-producing wings somewhere near the COG and then canards or a tail somewhere else to provide the moment.

For an air-to-air missile, where mass is low, speed is high, and maneuverability is more important than efficiency then you might be able to get away with no main wings and instead rely have canards and a tail to provide the lift. They both are located away from the COG so have leverage and are together capable of more maneuverability than just a tail or canard alone, but since there are two of them there are two degrees of freedom so you can still have independently control lift.

**EDIT:** It was pointed out that the tail on the sidewinder does not have control surfaces so does not participate in maneuvering. This is conjecture but there might be aerodynamic interference issues with the rear airfoils being too close to the front airfoils.

It could also simply be asking too from the response of the canards to have the rear airfoils closer to the COG.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, however note that the tail of the sidewinder is not articulated (besides the rollerons). the stinger also does not have an articulated tail.

Comment: @Drew I guess it's not. But those rollerons are pretty important.

Comment: I understand why the fins are needed to produce lift, but I expected them to be closer to the CG for maneuverability (as with a plane).

Comment: Afik they just cancel out roll so the tracker can do its thing. They're totally passive. Super cool mechanism though.

Comment: @Drew But where else are you going to put them?

Comment: Closer to the CG, like on the javelin.

Comment: My current understanding after considering your points, is that the tail "balances out" the canards to give the missile a small amount of stability (tendency to turn towards the direction of motion) but not too much. I hadn't considered that the canards also sort of act like wings, even when in the neutral position.

Comment: Yeah that point I said about the independent lift and maneuvering moment is still true even with a fixed tail. Moving the tail to the COG might be asking too much of from the response of the canards.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that for a long skinny anything travelling longways, the aerodynamic center for pitch and yaw moments is 25% from the nose, just like the lift center for a flat plate is 25% from the leading edge. And the aerodynamic moments work to increase the perturbation - forward feedback - assuming the CoG is further aft. Given a tiny perturbation, the missile wants to pivot 90 degrees and go sideways. You have to put the fins behind the CoG so that they provide a corrective moment (negative feedback in pitch and yaw) that is larger than the perturbation's forward feed back from the missile body.

Additionally, the missile has to carry properly on the pilon and launch in a controlled manner from all the planes that carry it. There were a lot of separation problems during launch testing. They still have separation problems during testing today.

Pull the ink out of a cheap Bic pen and drop it from about 10 feet. It will start to turn sideways. Play with scotch tape fins until it falls straight.

[image]

Below is good intro to "finner" missile stability derivatives. The purpose of the document is to derive correction factors for wind tunnels, but it presents the uncorrected stability derivatives as the starting point. See in particular section II - Intro to slender body theory.

https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA040670.pdf

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically as speed increases the size of the wings decreases.

Wings or tailfins are need to give directional control and that is related to speed as well.

If everyone could park at speed like this:

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/3l31bNE6LT0)

But most drivers can’t park that well even going slowly…

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, but I was wondering why the fins are not closer to the CG.